# How to add a variables library to NX workspace?

Tags: nrwl-nx, nrwl, nx-workspace, nx.dev

I have a NX workspace with a NestJS API and an Angular client project (see folder structure).

It has an `api-interfaces` library shared between the Angular client and the API, as appears below:

[image]

How can I add another library for constants and variables shared between client and api?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a lib in the same way:

```
npx nx generate @nx/js:library lib-data
```

In the prompt you choose jest and tsc, to make it compatible. The new lib contains a lib-data.ts file which you can fill with all your data:

```
export const max = 5;
export const allowedFormats = ['image/jpeg', 'image/png'];
```

Just import the lib in the same way like the interface lib. Then you are able to use all exported constants.